# Cannot put div over a image

Tags: html, css

hi i am trying to place a div over a image. i cant place this image as background image, because this image will be responsive. i am trying the following css,

```css
#slider {
    margin:0 33%;
    width:67%;
    position:relative;
}

#slider img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#slider #caption {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    opacity:.4;
    z-index:2;
}
```

---

```
<div id="slider">
  <img src="~/Content/Home/banner.jpg" />
  <div id="caption">President Installation</div>
</div>
```

can anybody tell where the error is.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `top` and `left` styles can position this element, because of `position:absolute`:

```
#slider #caption {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fff;
    opacity:.4;
    z-index:2;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/M9erv/1/)

Comment: it is worked , but i have one doubt it placed the top of image, i want to place it in the bottom

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 1):

Just set the top position of the caption. See the [Live demo](http://jsbin.com/ItAroPu/1/edit)

```
#slider #caption {
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:50px;    top:200px;
     background-color:#fff;
     opacity:.4;
     z-index:2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the  #caption div is to sit over the img you need to set the position of the image first.

```
#slider img {
 width:100%; height: auto;
 position:relative
}
```